# Closed Monoidal Structures On The Category Of Complete Topological Vector Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Context: The category of Banach spaces, with the projective tensor product is a closed monoidal category.

**Question 1**: Is there a tensor product on the category of complete topological vector spaces, such that the monoidal stucture is closed?

**Question 2**: what are the "natural/nice" topologies to put on the set of continuous linear maps between two ctvs?

**Question 3**: Is it different if instead we use Fréchet (or nuclear Fréchet) spaces?